# HtmlAgilityPack HtmlNodeCollection returning NULL , shouldn't

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I made a simple program for fetching youtube users in comments.
This is the code

```
string html;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            html = client.DownloadString("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ER5EnjskCvE");
        }
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        HtmlNodeCollection nodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='comments-view']/ul[1]/li[1]/a/span/span/span/span/img");
        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodeCollection)
        {
            data.Add(node.GetAttributeValue("alt",null));
        }
```

But i have a problem that my nodeCollection is returning null.
For the XPath i used copy XPath option in chrome under F12

Comment: To get your answer you just need to debug it, by checking the value of `html` after it's being downloaded by the `WebClient`. I have just done that for you, and it is because the HTML downloaded by WebClient is just the basic Javascript that is used to then render the full page. Therefore, HtmlAgilityPack won't "see" anything past the JS. I would suggest just ditching HtmlAgilityPack altogether and using an API designed for YouTube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Comment: Thanks, will check out the YT API

Answer (score 0):

try this replace "*" , "div" 
`"/html/body//div[@id='comments-view']/ul[1]/li[1]/a/span/span/span/span/img"`